# is setting up a cron job in cpanel all you need to do to run a php script

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job via cpanel. I have done so, but the problem is my php file contains a simple mail funtion to test if it works. It is not working.

I have found a few detailed tutorials about how to set up cron jobs, but they are complicated and most of it doesn't apply to cpanel, and a quick search here revealed no similar questions.

Is all I need to do is input the timing and command and the php file should execute??

Here is the command I have used in cPanel:

```
*/3 *   *   *   * /home/stretch045/public_html/scripts/whazzup.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is the whazzup.php file:

```
<?php
//Script is run through cron

mail('stretch045@hotmail.com','test','test123');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you use GUI of cPanel to set the Cron job.

So set your cron timing as something like as follows.

[image]

And in command, write

```
php /home/******file location*****/file.php
```

I use this in my cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You cant execute a PHP File - except you add the shebang header to the php script.

If you set the file permissions to execute for the correct group, you could execute this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
<?php
// ...
```

But you can also just modify the cronjob definition and add the php interpreter

```
*/3 *   *   *   * /usr/bin/php5 /home/stretch045/public_html/scripts/whazzup.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It might be possible, your php interpreter is installed somewhere else or named different.
To locate the correct PHP interpreter, you could use `whereis`

Comment: I have tried using PHP_BINDIR and found the binary directory is /usr/bin/ but how do I use whereis to get the php interpreter file name?? I have searched and not found where people are putting it into